# How to include first a CMake generated config.h conflicting with 3rd party files?

Tags: c++, cmake

I use CMake to generate a config.h file. I thought it was better to generate it in the build folder and not the source folder, because it will not be committed in the versioning system.
Because of that, I had to add an include directory to my target, and include my file like `<config.h>` instead of `"config.h"`.

```
set(GENERATED_HEADER_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/geninclude)

execute_process(COMMAND git describe
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE version_description
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/config.h.in"
               "${GENERATED_HEADER_DIR}/config.h")

# ... target configuration

target_include_directories(my_target
                           PRIVATE ${GENERATED_HEADER_DIR}
                           PRIVATE ${SOME_LIB_I_NEED})
```

My problem is: some lib has aslo exposed a *config.h* file and the both files are messing up each other during the build.

Edit: the project is built to webassembly so apparently it needs to compile everything at once and cannot link to bin libs as it is usually done with C++ projects.

---

Is there a way to to include my own generated file with `".h"` instead of `<.h>` without putting the file into my *src* dir?

Or it there a way to prioritize the include so my code will include my generated file and the lib includes its own? I don't think I can modify the lib CMake config though...

Comment: "Or is there a way to prioritize the include" - Include directories are searched in the **order** they are listed. However, maintaining this order would be quite tricky. It would be much more simpler to have **unique include name** for your config file. E.g. `#include <XXX/config.h>` or `#include <XXX_config.h>`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes that's the workaround I had in mind in the first place, but I was wondering if there was a better solution, _config.h_ seems to be a standard and many projects don't need to prefix it (it is actually only 1 lib of a dozen that conflicts with my code)

Comment: `are messing up each other during the build.` is very vague. Does current setup not work? The library should build and your target should see first `config.h`. And why would you include `SOME_LIB_I_NEED` with `target_include_directories` - wouldn't you want to use `target_add_libraries`?

Comment: Name `config.h` is perfectly usable as a name of **non-interface** header, that is its directory is included only when one build the library itself. If you need a configuration header as **interface** one, then you are better to make its name **unique** (by prefixing it).

Comment: @KamilCuk I think it was made like this because the target is webassembly and cannot manage libraries (but I am not sure, I am just taking over this project). With this config my build does not see my `config.h` and includes the file from the 3rd party, which leads to compile error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's the thing, my header is not interface, it is only internal but I put it in the build dir instead of source dir, so I have to include as an external file, and I am asking if there is a better way to deal with this. A better way to generate a header and include it as an internal file.

Comment: `does not see` - so did you inspect your build system to see what include paths in what order are passed to the compiler? Add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)` or compile with `make VERBOSE=1` or similar. `my build` - by "my build" you mean while building the 3rd party library or your `my_target`? Is your `my_target` a library or a executable? Please include more info for an [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

You should aim to keep your include paths unique, so that this cannot happen.

One way to achieve this is by moving the majority of includes to their own subdirectory. So instead of `#include <config.h>` you could use `#include <MyProject/config.h>`.

```
configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/config.h.in"
               "${GENERATED_HEADER_DIR}/MyProject/config.h")
```

If you end up in a situation where this is not possible, eg. because both of the headers are part of third-party libraries A and B not under your control, you need to solve the problem by allowing each `.cpp` file to only make use of either lib A or lib B, but never both. As soon as both libraries are usable by the same source file, you get the conflict on the include files, which is *not resolvable*. Any clever hackery regarding the order of include directories on the build command line or `#include <>` vs. `include ""` is extremely fragile and non-portable.

Comment: That's what I did, I used a filename more specific. But I was curious about a cleaner solution.